# Measure distance with ultrasonic sensor and Raspberry

Tags: python, measure

I am trying to measure a distance with ultrasonic sensor and everything looks well but when I leave the program for a some minutes (3-4 minutes) working, the program stops the measure of distance.

I need that the program dont stops because I need it to a security alarm. The program collects every one second a distance and show it in scree. But if distance is more than 10, the program shows a alert message and dont show the distance until it is less of 10. Following you can see the code:

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


# Usamos la referencia BOARD para los pines GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

# Definimos los pines que vamos a usar
GPIO_TRIGGER = 11
GPIO_ECHO = 13
GPIO_LED = 15

# Configuramos los pines como entradas y salidas
GPIO.setup(GPIO_TRIGGER,GPIO.OUT)  # Trigger
GPIO.setup(GPIO_ECHO,GPIO.IN)      # Echo
GPIO.setup(GPIO_LED ,GPIO.OUT) #Led


# -----------------------
# Definimos algunas funciones
# -----------------------

def medida():
  # Esta funcion mide una distancia
  GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, True)
  time.sleep(0.00001)
  GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)
  start = time.time()

  while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO)==0:
    start = time.time()

  while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO)==1:
    stop = time.time()

  elapsed = stop-start
  distancia = (elapsed * 34300)/2

  return distancia

def media_distancia():
  # Esta funcion recoge 3 medidas
  # y devuelve la media de las 3.
  distancia1=medida()
  time.sleep(0.1)
  distancia2=medida()
  time.sleep(0.1)
  distancia3=medida()
  distancia = distancia1 + distancia2 + distancia3
  distancia = distancia / 3
  return distancia


# -----------------------
# Programa principal
# -----------------------


print ("Medida con sensor de ultrasonidos")

# Ponemos el Trigger en falso (low)
GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)
# Ponemos el Led en falso (low)
GPIO.output(GPIO_LED, False)

# Metemos el bloque principal en un Try para asi poder
# comprobar si el usuario presiona Ctrl + C
# y poder ejecutar una limpieza del GPIO, esto tambien
# evita el usuario tener que ver muchos mensajes de error
try:
  while True: # Este bucle se repite siempre

# Lo primero que hago es medir la distancia
      distancia = media_distancia()
# Compruebo si la distancia es menor que 10
# Si es menor que 10 muestro la distancia por pantalla

      if distancia < 10:
        distancia = media_distancia() # Medidos la distancia 
        print ("Distancia: %.1f" % distancia, " - " , "Fecha:", time.strftime("%c")) # Mostramos la distancia por pantalla
        GPIO.output(GPIO_LED, False)
        time.sleep(1) # Esperamos 1 segundo
        distancia = media_distancia()
        a = 0 # Utilizo la variable a para poder para el proceso mas adelante

# Pregunto si la variable a es igual a 1
# Si lo es no hago nada y repito el if anterior
      if a == 1:
        pass
# Pero si no es 1 le asigno el valor 0
# Para poder seguir con el IF siguiente
      else: 
        a = 0
      if distancia > 10 and a == 0: # Si la distancia es mayor que 10cms
           print ("La distancia es mayor de 10 cms. Alarma activada!!", " - ", "Fecha:", time.strftime("%c")) # Se interrumpe el bucle y se muestra un aviso
           GPIO.output(GPIO_LED, True)  
           a = 1 # Pongo la variable en 1 para parar el proceso y que no se repita 
           distancia = media_distancia() # Seguimos midiento la distancia
           while distancia < 10: # Pero si la distancia vuelve a ser menor de 10
             break # Se termina este bucle y volvemos al principio nuevamente

except KeyboardInterrupt: # Si el usuario presiona crtl + C

  # Limpiamos los pines GPIO y salimos del programa

  print ("Apagando LED")
  time.sleep(1)
  GPIO.output(GPIO_LED, False)
  print ("Limpiando GPIO")
  GPIO.cleanup()
  print ("GPIO limpio")
  print ("Saliendo...")
  time.sleep(1)
```

Why does the program stops after some minutes?

Comment: Could you show an output example?

Comment: why you just dont use a logger

Comment: What do you mean by "the program stops measuring distance?" Does the program terminate or it just keeps executing without measuring distances? If it's the latter then probably gets stuck in one of the loops in the function medida(). Put debugging prints in your code to know where it gets stuck. You should put timeouts in your loops, so if something gets stuck you can clean the procedure and start again.

Comment: Yes, is the last you said. The program is running but is not collecting and showing distances. The problem is that I do not how to put debugging prints...

Answer (score 1):

In your function `medida():` you are triggering the sensor using:

```
GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, True)
time.sleep(0.00001)
GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)
```

Then waiting that the ECHO sets to 0 to start counting time and finally waiting the ECHO to set to 1 to stop counting time

```
 while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO)==0:
    start = time.time()
 while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO)==1:
    stop = time.time()
```

Now imagine that any of this two transitions doesn't happen:

- maybe the ECHO never gets to 1 because there's no ECHO returned at all (no object, misbehavior of the sensor, misconnection...)
- or maybe the ECHO is already 1 when you wait for it to get to 0 (you are doing a time.sleep(0.00001) after the rising edge of TRIGGER. In this time maybe the ECHO already gets to 0 in some cases...

If any of this two things happen, your program will wait forever, which is probably what is happening.
You should include a timeout in your loops, so if thins "hang" you can call the function to trigger the sensor again.

Comment: So, immediately after  While I should put a time.sleep (1) ?? In both of Whiles? Or what's your idea? Thank you so much friend!!

Answer (score 0):

My best guest is that there is an exception somewhere on your code. Please, try this version and add an example of the output:

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


# Usamos la referencia BOARD para los pines GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

# Definimos los pines que vamos a usar
GPIO_TRIGGER = 11
GPIO_ECHO = 13
GPIO_LED = 15

# Configuramos los pines como entradas y salidas
GPIO.setup(GPIO_TRIGGER,GPIO.OUT)  # Trigger
GPIO.setup(GPIO_ECHO,GPIO.IN)      # Echo
GPIO.setup(GPIO_LED ,GPIO.OUT) #Led


# -----------------------
# Definimos algunas funciones
# -----------------------

def medida():
  # Esta funcion mide una distancia
  GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, True)
  time.sleep(0.00001)
  GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)
  start = time.time()

  while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO)==0:
    start = time.time()

  while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO)==1:
    stop = time.time()

  elapsed = stop-start
  distancia = (elapsed * 34300)/2

  return distancia

def media_distancia():
  # Esta funcion recoge 3 medidas
  # y devuelve la media de las 3.
  distancia1=medida()
  time.sleep(0.1)
  distancia2=medida()
  time.sleep(0.1)
  distancia3=medida()
  distancia = distancia1 + distancia2 + distancia3
  distancia = distancia / 3
  return distancia


# -----------------------
# Programa principal
# -----------------------


print ("Medida con sensor de ultrasonidos")

# Ponemos el Trigger en falso (low)
GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)
# Ponemos el Led en falso (low)
GPIO.output(GPIO_LED, False)

# Metemos el bloque principal en un Try para asi poder
# comprobar si el usuario presiona Ctrl + C
# y poder ejecutar una limpieza del GPIO, esto tambien
# evita el usuario tener que ver muchos mensajes de error
continuar = True
while continuar: # Este bucle se repite siempre
  try:

  # Lo primero que hago es medir la distancia
        distancia = media_distancia()
  # Compruebo si la distancia es menor que 10
  # Si es menor que 10 muestro la distancia por pantalla

        if distancia < 10:
          distancia = media_distancia() # Medidos la distancia 
          print ("Distancia: %.1f" % distancia, " - " , "Fecha:", time.strftime("%c")) # Mostramos la distancia por pantalla
          GPIO.output(GPIO_LED, False)
          time.sleep(1) # Esperamos 1 segundo
          distancia = media_distancia()
          a = 0 # Utilizo la variable a para poder para el proceso mas adelante

  # Pregunto si la variable a es igual a 1
  # Si lo es no hago nada y repito el if anterior
        if a == 1:
          pass
  # Pero si no es 1 le asigno el valor 0
  # Para poder seguir con el IF siguiente
        else: 
          a = 0
        if distancia > 10 and a == 0: # Si la distancia es mayor que 10cms
             print ("La distancia es mayor de 10 cms. Alarma activada!!", " - ", "Fecha:", time.strftime("%c")) # Se interrumpe el bucle y se muestra un aviso
             GPIO.output(GPIO_LED, True)  
             a = 1 # Pongo la variable en 1 para parar el proceso y que no se repita 
             distancia = media_distancia() # Seguimos midiento la distancia
             while distancia < 10: # Pero si la distancia vuelve a ser menor de 10
               break # Se termina este bucle y volvemos al principio nuevamente

  except KeyboardInterrupt: # Si el usuario presiona crtl + C
    continuar = False

  except (Exception) as  error:
    print (str(error))

    # Limpiamos los pines GPIO y salimos del programa

  print ("Apagando LED")
  time.sleep(1)
  GPIO.output(GPIO_LED, False)
  print ("Limpiando GPIO")
  GPIO.cleanup()
  print ("GPIO limpio")
  print ("Saliendo...")
  time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to find the reason of such is simple **USE A LOGGER**!
without blackbox you will hardly find the reason why your place crash!!

python has one ready to use, check the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html)

import the logger module:

```
import logging
```

configure it to create a file...

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
```

and begging to log on every spot you find suspicious

```
logging.warning('Watch out!')  # will print a message to the console
logging.info('I told you so')  # will not print anything
```